# Validating input and using system()

Tags: c++, validation

What I am doing is bringing in a hostname and a username, the hostname can be 255 characters, can not end with numbers and can only contain letters, numbers and '-' and '.'. A user name I want to have only characters. I then want to output these using the system() command to run it within a terminal and it'll log on.

Example input:

someserver.com

Matt

And the system command will use finger to log on

The problems I need a little help with are throwing an exception for the '-' and '.' with the hostname and my if loop checking for user validation always comes as invalid. For using the system if anyone has an example I would appreciate it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{


printf("Enter your Host Name; it must be characters and not more than 255");
char hostName[254];
int len2;
fgets(hostName, sizeof(hostName), stdin);
rewind (stdin);
len2 = strlen(hostName);
if(hostName[len2-1] == '\n') hostName[--len2] = '\0';
if(len2 >254 ||!isalpha(hostName[len2-1]))
{
    printf("Invalid Host Name");


}


printf("Enter your User Name; it must be characters and not more than 20");
char userName[19];
int len;
fgets(userName, sizeof(userName), stdin);
rewind (stdin);
len = strlen(userName);
if(userName[len-1] == '\n') userName[--len] = '\0';
if(len >19 || !isalpha(userName[19]))
{

    printf("Invalid User Name");


}

//Use system to output the command 

// printf("/usr/bin/ssh'hostname/usr/bin/finger'username" );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: use `sprintf()` to construct the command line by substituting the inputs.

Comment: Why are you using all those C strings and I/O functions in a C++ program?

Comment: This started out as C++ and is being moved to C

Comment: Use `strcspn()` to search the string for characters outside the allowed set.

Comment: sprintf(buffer1,"ssh %s usr/bin/finger %s",hostName,userName);
system((char*)buffer1);

Comment: worked for the system and now this program does what I want but its not yet secure for the host-name; is there an easier method than searching all of the characters I dont want this strcspn()?

Comment: `strcspn()` lets you search for anything outside the list of characters you _do_ want. So it's perfect for you.

Comment: I appreciate it Barmar